# Causing a MalformedURLException (Android)

Tags: java, android, exception, malformedurlexception

I am trying to induce a MalformedURLException in my code to test my handling of it, however no matter what I try I cannot seem to cause it. (I've passed in a complete nonsense non-url string and it still does not arise, I simply get a null response)

I am aware that android developers reference describes:

> This exception is thrown when a program attempts to create an URL from an incorrect specification.

I was wondering how do I create/provide such an incorrect specification

This is the code I'm trying to execute

```
     try {
        HttpData data = request.composeHttpData();
        //URL url = new URL(composeUrl(data));
        URL url2 = new URL("mydomain:-2/invalidPort");
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) getHttpClient().open(url2);
        conn.setRequestMethod(data.getMethod());

        //authentication
        addAuthentication(conn);

        //post body
        if (data.getMethod() == POST) {
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            data.writePostBody(conn.getOutputStream());
            conn.getOutputStream().close();
        }

        if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            response.consumeResponse(conn.getInputStream());
        }

        response.setResponseHttpCode(conn.getResponseCode());

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Error("Malformed URL encountered");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return response;
    }
```

When I try to debug the code it seems to jump from the Url instantiation to the return statement.

Comment: remove the http:// from the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a port number less than -1

```
    URL url = new URL("http://mydomain:-2/invalidPort");
```

Comment: On my nexus 7 kitkat 4.4.2 I obtain java.net.MalformedURLException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port < 0: -2

Comment: I've further expanded the example. I think there must be a deeper error somewhere along the way?

Comment: please post the stacktrace, I've tried also on genymotion simulator and the MalformedURLException is raised as expected

Comment: I think my problem was with the use of the finally statement. Even though I am throwing an error on the exception the app doesn't crash (as I want it to) but carries on anyway.

Comment: Try to move the return statement as last line on try block and remove the finally block. Consider the finally should contain only cleanup code

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
throw new MalformedURLException("Testing!");
```